# What happens, if I place a xmlns:f="foo" inside the body?

Tags: html, xml-namespaces

Assume this HTML5 page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head><!-- some content --></head>
 <body>
  <div id="a" xmlns:f="http://exampleurl.jp/">
   <a href="#">test</a>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

This question includes the fact, that the namespace `f` is not used inside the document and `http://exampleurl.jp/` is not reachable.

Will browsers ...

- be ready for usage of that namespace inside the div `#a` (best case)
- ignore the namespace definition (I'd be okay with that)
- fail because `http://exampleurl.jp/` is not reachable (404) or at least contains no valid XML namespace definition (worst case)

... ?

And regardless of the browsers actual behaviour, how *should* they behave (per definition)?

Comment: What content-type should we assume? text/html or application/xhtml+xml? (Guessing the former since there is no xmlns on the root element.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browsers will ignore the attribute. According to  http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#elements-0 this XML like syntax for defining namespace aliases (in your example, making *f* an alias for the namespace *http://exampleurl.jp/*) is not supported.

In any case, namespace URIs do not have to actually map to anything on an actual website. The URI can be anything, since it is just used to differentiate local names that are the same, but are in different namespaces.